# Animating page transitions using ng-outlet

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to animate page enter and page leave transitions in angular 1.5 using ng-outlet like it is using the ng-view? If so how?

Comment: Ignore me I have it working now. Thanks for the down votes I knew you'd be out in force as usual!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you found your solution that I suggest that you self-answer the question for future uses having the same problem, or delete it

Answer (score 0):

Okay, well since an answer should be provided:

1) You need to pull in angular-animate for your version of AngularJS using bower

2) Add ngAnimate as a dependency to your apps module

3) Then write some CSS3 animations or transitions to be used

```
ng-outlet.ng-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    transition-duration: 1000ms;
}

ng-outlet.ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}

ng-outlet.ng-leave {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-duration: 1000ms;
}

ng-outlet.ng-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Angular will detect these animations and/or transitions and provide access in it's event loop to do the animation or transition.  You can observe this by looking at the markup in Chrome DevTools.  If the above CSS exists you'll see the ng-enter, ng-enter-active, etc being applied to the ngOutlet.  If they are removed the event classes are no longer applied to ngOutlet.